# Is it a plot hole if a scene that seems to be from the future doesn't match what actually happens in the future (spoiler alert)?

Tags: creative-writing, plot

Is it a plot hole if a scene that seems to be from the future doesn't match what actually happens in the future?

There's this scene in the beginning of Gurren Lagan that doesn't seem to match what happens in the future. Is this a plot hole, especially if you need an explanation from the authors to make sense of it (even if the explanation does make sense)?

> ANN: In a previous convention panel, it was mentioned that the first
> episode's introductory scene tells a slightly different story than the
> ending because the story changed during production. What were some of
> the reasons as to why the story changed from the introductory scene to
> the way we know it now?
>
> Otsuka: That's where we thought we were going to go when we first
> depicted it. However, by the time we got there it had grown so much
> beyond the scale of what we had originally imagined it was going to
> be, therefore slight differences would be noticed.

https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2008-07-28/gainax-on-gurren-lagann

Fans theorized that the scene depicted a timeline where the character made a bad choice, but it seems like it was sort of a mistake, and the animators used the fans' theories as headcannon, but should it still be considered to be a plot hole, and how do you avoid such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call that a "plot hole", but it's certainly a problem. I think of a plot hole as an inconsistency or irrationality in the plot. Like in chapter 1 you say that Bob is a highly skilled martial arts expert but in chapter 4 he gets beaten up by an ordinary guy with no explanation. This is an "inconsistency", but to my mind not in the same sense. One could quibble over such definitions endlessly, I suppose.